# Groovy on Raspberry Pi - Install hangs on PCL cmake (qemu)

Tags: ros, build-from-source, raspberrypi, ros-groovy, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source

Following the qemu chroot method, I am trying to build ROS-G 'mobile' variant and have had quite a bit of success up to now. During the build of PCL, the build hangs on cmake.

Suggestions?

Relevant Build Output:
(101 packages are built ok above this point.)
==> Processing plain cmake package: 'pcl'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/groovy/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl'
==> make -j1 -l1 in '/opt/ros/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55161/groovy-on-raspberry-pi---install-hangs-on-pcl-cmake-(qemu)/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the same steps, but was actually successful in compiling natively, with exception of the robot_pose_ekf (I just asked a question on that).

PCL takes around 2/3 days to compile natively on the Pi, and uses around 1G of memory. The error for blowing up RAM is cryptic, GCC gives some Internal Error and asks you to fill in a bug report. Raspbian resets swap size on every boot, so you have to increse it before every compilation.

From your paste, seems like it got past the cmake phase and into the make phase (check the last ==>).

My 2 cents: just take 3 days and do it on the Pi itself. There are some tweeks, but seems like it is a good path.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Marco Poli](https://answers.ros.org/users/4357/marco-poli/) with karma: 86 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0